# asymptote in RStudio

Tags: asymptote, rstudio

Recently, I found an amazing fact: if we go the `art of problem solving` website, with `copy` and `paste` to `.Rmd` in `RStudio`, we could directly have the `latex` codes for math equations. That is very nice. But for the picture part, the `asymptote` code could not be recognized by `RStudio`

For example, here[example](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2022_AMC_8_Problems/Problem_21), the code is like this

```
Problem
Steph scored $15$ baskets out of $20$ attempts in the first half of a game, and $10$ baskets out of $10$ attempts in the second half. Candace took $12$ attempts in the first half and $18$ attempts in the second. In each half, Steph scored a higher percentage of baskets than Candace. Surprisingly they ended with the same overall percentage of baskets scored. How many more baskets did Candace score in the second half than in the first?[asy] size(7cm); draw((-8,27)--(72,27)); draw((16,0)--(16,35)); draw((40,0)--(40,35)); label("12", (28,3)); draw((25,6.5)--(25,12)--(31,12)--(31,6.5)--cycle); draw((25,5.5)--(31,5.5)); label("18", (56,3)); draw((53,6.5)--(53,12)--(59,12)--(59,6.5)--cycle); draw((53,5.5)--(59,5.5)); draw((53,5.5)--(59,5.5)); label("20", (28,18)); label("15", (28,24)); draw((25,21)--(31,21)); label("10", (56,18)); label("10", (56,24)); draw((53,21)--(59,21)); label("First Half", (28,31)); label("Second Half", (56,31)); label("Candace", (2.35,6)); label("Steph", (0,21)); [/asy]$\textbf{(A) } 7\qquad\textbf{(B) } 8\qquad\textbf{(C) } 9\qquad\textbf{(D) } 10\qquad\textbf{(E) } 11$

Solution 1 (Inequalities)
Let $x$ be the number of shots that Candace made in the first half, and let $y$ be the number of shots Candace made in the second half. Since Candace and Steph took the same number of attempts, with an equal percentage of baskets scored, we have $x+y=10+15=25.$ In addition, we have the following inequalities:\[\frac{x}{12}<\frac{15}{20} \implies x<9,\]and\[\frac{y}{18}<\frac{10}{10} \implies y<18.\]Pairing this up with $x+y=25$ we see the only possible solution is $(x,y)=(8,17),$ for an answer of $17-8 = \boxed{\textbf{(C) } 9}.$
```

everything can go through smoothly except the picture part (the asymptote part).

I wonder if we could run `asymptote` in `RStudio`. By the way, they have tutorials here[tutorial](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Asymptote_(Vector_Graphics_Language))

Comment: Are you only interested in a solution using RStudio? It would be simpler to copy and paste into a text document and run LaTeX and Asymptote directly, without using Rmd as intermediate format.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. But I just wonder if we could do it in RStudio. thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. This has nothing to do with RStudio, which is just an IDE (but it's true it greatly simplifies the process).

You have to put the Asymptote code in a chunk with the `asy` engine:

````
``{r asy-example, engine = "asy", fig.cap = "Asymptote 3D Example", fig.ext = 'png'}
import graph3;
import palette;
size(200,300,keepAspect=false);
currentprojection=orthographic(10,10,30);
currentlight=(10,10,5);
triple f(pair t) {return (exp(t.x)*cos(t.y),exp(t.x)*sin(t.y),t.y);}
surface s=surface(f,(-4,-2pi),(0,4pi),8,16,Spline);
s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()));
draw(s,render(merge=true));
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I can run it in my RStudio, but with the only the chart pop up. I cannot put the chart into the html or pdf file knitted from RStudio. I wonder if you could that. Actually, when I try to knit to html file, I got the error message like this: running: asy asy7a8c6e357628.asy -f png -o asy7a8c6e357628.png
Warning in file.rename(f1, f2) :
  cannot rename file 'asy7a8c6e357628.png' to 'figure/-1.png', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Comment: @Pai Strange. Maybe you have to create the `figure` subfolder?

Comment: I wonder how I can do that? thanks!